# How to send values from the changed row to a trigger in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I want to create a trigger, somehow like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo 
AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON bar 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE baz(NEW.id);
```

The part with NEW.id doesn't work. How can I send values from the changed row (id for instance) to the trigger-function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigger function (procedure) knows `NEW` and `OLD` automatically. No need to pass those as parameters.
Read more in the chapter on [Trigger Procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.htmler) in the manual:

> When a PL/pgSQL function is called as a trigger, several special
>   variables are created automatically in the top-level block. They are:
>
> NEW
>
> Data type RECORD; variable holding the new database row for INSERT/UPDATE operations in row-level triggers. This variable is NULL
>   in statement-level triggers and for DELETE operations.